# Custom vision internal failures

Tags: computer-vision

I'm making a series of 20 or so batch calls into the cognitive predictive service on https://southcentralus.api.cognitive.microsoft.com/customvision/v1.1/Prediction and it looks like as of 2/21/2018 the first five or six calls are returned with 500 internal server error, however, after that the remaining calls in the batch  are fine. Has anything changed or anyone else experiencing this? BTW- I'm using a test / development subscription and have not exceeded the daily limit.

Comment: Actually, further testing indicates the failures are completely random, regardless if I use the same image or a series of different images.

Comment: if you want to know if something changed in an api you should refer to the changelog of that api or Microsoft